# Is it possible to use dataBase.executeNonQuery and use a return value from a stored proc?

Tags: c#, enterprise-library-5

I have done some research and found a few ideas on how we can use a return value from a stored proc like:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = parameterStatement.getQuery();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SeqName", "SeqNameValue");

    var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var result = returnParameter.Value;
}
```

but i am using something like this:

```
Database.AddInParameter();
```

where i do not have to open and close connections..

Can some body help me to understand if it is possible to use Direction.Returnvalue using DataBase approach?

Sorry for a bit un-organized question :) please feel free to ask if anything is not clear

Comment: What about `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` ? I'm not sure what you're asking for. Do you specifically want to use a Return-Parameter or du you just want to access the return value from your proc?

Comment: i just want to access return value from my proc.. lemme check out cmd.ExecuteScalar if it suits my requirement.. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @Patrik Eckebrecht 1  thanks for ur comment. Actually i wanted to use EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database object  with execute non query method instead of command . execute<something>

As the code is pre-written and i dont want to change it much

Comment: Ah ok. Not very clear. Maybe rephrase a bit for others to understand better.

Comment: i was in a bit hurry so could not format and phrase my question in a better way :) but i got a solution that worked perfectly fine for me i used DataBase.outParameter ..

Answer (score -1):

use database.outParameter for parameters that return value